# Lost token FCM with google api

Tags: android

I need to retrieve all registered FCM token directly from google.

> there a way to retrieve running a Query?

Regards,

Diego.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood working with FCM it is not possible directly. In official documentation of FCM a developer is responsible to pass token to App server when it was obtained or refreshed (onTokenRefresh() callback of FirebaseInstanceIdService).

I think that Google made it with intention to omit the role of storage of any data in FCM and reduce traffic in this way.